# Show that for Chebyshev polynomials satisfy $(1-x^2)T'_k + kxT_k -kT_{k-1} = 0$

Tags: polynomials, approximation, computational-mathematics, chebyshev-polynomials

$T_n(x)$ is the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind. I was wondering how to show the following recurrence relationship:
$$ (1-x^2)T'_k + kxT_k -kT_{k-1} = 0$$

This recurrence form also shows up as equation (2) in this paper: https://www.mathsjournal.com/pdf/2016/vol1issue1/PartA/1-1-18-475.pdf

But it doesn't seem to provide the proof.

Edit:
Is it possible to prove it using only the three-term recurrent relation: $T_{k+1} = 2xT_k - T_{k-1}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure you can quite call this a recurrence relation, since it doesn't let you find the next $T_k.$

Answer (score 1):

Plugging in $x=\cos t$,
$$\begin{split}
(1-x^2)T'_k(x) + kxT_k(x) -kT_{k-1}(x) &=(1-\cos^2 t)T^\prime_k(\cos t) + k\cos(t) T_k(\cos t) -kT_{k-1}(\cos t)  \\
&= \sin^2(t) \frac{k\sin(kt)}{\sin t}+k\cos(t)\cos(kt)-k\cos((k-1)t)\\
&= k\sin(t)\sin(kt)+k\cos(t)\cos(kt)\\
&-k\cos(kt)\cos t -k\sin(kt)\sin t \\
&=0
\end{split}$$
where we have used the fact that $T_n(\cos t)=\cos(nt)$ and by differentiation, $$(\sin t) T^\prime_k(\cos t)=n\sin(nt)$$
We have thus proven that for all $x\in[-1, 1]$, $$(1-x^2)T'_k(x) + kxT_k(x) -kT_{k-1}(x) = 0$$
This implies that this identity must be true as a polynomial equality.

Comment: That makes sense! Just curious.  Can it be shown using the recurrence relation ($T_{k+1} = 2xT_k-T_{k-1}$)?

Comment: Yep, the same idea can be applied for that one too.